# Heat Bar for Accuracy

Tags: javascript

Is there a javascript chart that looks something like this: [image: heat bar]
 that you can place the accuracy of a point on this.  So instead of Black to Red, it would be Red on the ends and green in the middle, and the further it was from the center the less accurate the reading?

Comment: Shouldnt be too hard to write, effectively you just need to write a slider control that maps to the design you have provided above. see this example: https://jqueryui.com/slider/. I presume from your question that you will need to specify the value for which the slider should point to. In that case also have a look here https://forum.jquery.com/topic/change-value-of-slider-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this plot.ly colorscale:

https://plot.ly/javascript/heatmap-and-contour-colorscales/#hot-colorscale

if that doesn't work for you, and you need more control, you can use d3.js color scales directly

http://synthesis.sbecker.net/articles/2012/07/16/learning-d3-part-6-scales-colors

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1, 0, 1])
    .range(["red", "white", "green"]);

color(-1)   // "#ff0000" red
color(-0.5) // "#ff8080" pinkish
color(0)    // "#ffffff" white
color(0.5)  // "#80c080" getting greener
color(0.7)  // "#4da64d" almost there..
color(1)    // "#008000" totally green!
```

Comment: Would I be able to add a line across it to indicate where the current score was at?

Comment: @Rob yes you would